# Eclipse installer not showing any packages

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

When trying to install eclipse, when I run the installer I just get a blank box with no packages to select. [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeVHL.png)
Any idea on how I could fix it, I have my java environment variable and java_home both set to the \bin location for both my java installations.  The versions of java I currently am using are jdk 8 and I got jdk 16 to see if that might fix the issue but it didn't.  As well, there weren't any errors or anything it just shows the empty box and shows that there's an update but I'm not sure what it's trying to update.  Any idea how I could fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Solution that worked for me:
Ok so after some fiddling around I had to search "eclipse" in the search all bar in windows.  Then after some scrolling I was able to find the file "eclipse-isnt.exe" and after running that it showed the stuff to download and solved my problem.  The "eclipse-isnt.exe" ended up being located in "C:/Users/(user)/AppData/Local/Temp/(random temp file)/eclipse-inst.exe".

Hope this helps out

Also running the file as administrator worked